# Making filtering a huge table more efficient

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, extract

I have two files.

- One .tsv inputFile; about 4 GB
- One .csv with Criteria (only a list of numbers)

I want to filter the entries of the inputFile with the conditions of the Criteria File and save the result in a new file.

That works quite well with the following code:

```
import csv
def filterFile (inputFile,output,CriteriaFile,columnToFilter):

read = csv.reader(open(inputFile, "r", encoding="utf8"),delimiter='\t')
write = csv.writer(open(output, "w"), delimiter='\t')

inFilterfile = open(CriteriaFile, "r")
filterCriteriaList = list(csv.reader(inFilterfile))

for row in read:
    if any( [x for x in filterCriteriaList if x[0] in row[columnToFilter]] ):
        write.writerow(row)

filterFile('hugefile.tsv','out.csv','criteria.csv',1)
```

The code works, but unfortunately it is rather slow. Is it possible to optimize it or is there a faster way for extracting entries from a big .tsv/.csv file based on a list stored in a different .csv and save the results in a new file?

Comment: short answer : use pandas or dask

Comment: Your question is missing some information which would make it easier to answer... how many lines/columns in your 4GB input file and your criteria file? What OS do you use? What CPU do you have? What disk(s) do you have?